# Winjs List Dispose

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-8.1, winjs, dispose

I am trying to optimise my app for windows 8. I have a WinJS.Binding.List and a page which will display a filtered projection of that list. Every time I access the page the filter will most likely be different so I want to dispose of the list when I leave the page.

Here is my filter:

```
            filteredListViewItems = Data.items.createFiltered(function (item) {
                if (item.project === certainProject) {
                        return item;
                };
            });
```

When I leave the page I then call:

```
           filteredListViewItems.dispose();
```

However if I put a breakpoint inside the function it still runs every time I add an item.

How can I remove this altogether?

Comment: If you put a break-point where? When is it firing that you don't expect?

Comment: Is your app targeting Windows 8.1 rather than Windows 8? The dispose model is new in WinJS for 8.1. 
Also, when do you call filteredListViewItems.dispose()? Is it in the unload handler for the PageControl?

Comment: Yes, I called filteredListViewItems.dispose() in the unload function for the page. 
The function that is firing is the top function that I have listed, even though I have disposed of filteredListViewItems the filter is still called when I add an item to my base WinJs list

Comment: Sorry to keep asking questions ... Are you using one of the templates that includes navigator.js? If so, the _navigating function will automatically dispose the page control (which should dispose all the child controls, too). Is your WinJS.Binding.List dynamically generated? If so, when is it generated?

Comment: No please ask away! Yes I am using navigator.js

I create my listview projection in init: funnction for the the page. I only navigate between pages using the navigator.js... what am i doing wrong!?

Comment: I don't think that it was intended for you to call dispose explicitly in your code (unless, say, you're updating the layout on a page without navigating away and need to destroy a control). The idea is that the page control and all its children are disposed when _navigating is called. At any rate, I'll investigate your scenario and see if I can figure out what's up.

Comment: I've tried to recreate your scenario a bit and I can't get it to repro. One more thought - if your filteredListViewItems variable doesn't need to be used on another page, you might try setting it to null in your call to PageControl.unload.